# Remove some elements stored in the list with the indexes present in other list

Tags: list, arraylist

Q:Remove some elements stored in the list with the indexes present in other list? for eg.
    List 1 has a, b, c, d, e and List 2 has 0,2 then a and c should be removed.

I have done a implementation of this ,not sure how efficent\in-efficent this is

```
public class RemoveByIndexFromOtherList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lOriginal = new ArrayList<String>();
        lOriginal.add("a");
        lOriginal.add("b");
        lOriginal.add("c");
        lOriginal.add("d");
        lOriginal.add("e");

        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        indexes.add(0);
        indexes.add(2);
        List<String> elemToRemove = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Integer index : indexes) {
            String b = lOriginal.get(index.intValue());
            elemToRemove.add(b);
        }

        for (String s : lOriginal) {
            if (elemToRemove.contains(s)) {} 
            else {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest, how this can be improved to a fair good efficient level

Comment: i dont think there is a better than storing the elements you want to remove and removing them afterward

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need an answer/recommendation.

Instead of removing you can create a new list and add indexes not present in the second list. And then just change a reference. In Your case if you have multiple "a"s in a list, all of them will get removed.

Suggestion:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveByIndexFromOtherList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lOriginal = new ArrayList<String>();
        lOriginal.add("a");
        lOriginal.add("b");
        lOriginal.add("c");
        lOriginal.add("d");
        lOriginal.add("e");
        lOriginal.add("a");

        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        indexes.add(0);
        indexes.add(2);

        List<String> newListOriginal = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i<lOriginal.size(); i++){
            if(!indexes.contains(i)){
                newListOriginal.add(lOriginal.get(i));
            }           
        }
        lOriginal = newListOriginal;

        for(String str: lOriginal){
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    }
}
```